# Do I pay egress fees when I serve requests?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cost-management, egress

I read this sentence

> If you are hosting a web application in the cloud, then you are
> probably used to paying data egress charges for your outbound traffic
> anyway, so you will be comfortable with this charging model.

in the following post https://www.logicata.com/blog/dont-get-caught-out-by-aws-data-egress-fees/

How are egress costs calculated? Is it based on all the outbound traffic of my apps? Even what would be served in a website? Or is it only when doing data transfers to servers outside of AWS?

Comment: When you serve outbound traffic from your server to a machine outside of AWS, that is by definition data transfer to a machine outside of AWS, so it egress.

Comment: Also if you serve requests to machines in another Availability Zone within the same region.